# Sharepoint fetchClientFactory is not updating the site url when called multiple time

Tags: javascript, node.js, sharepoint, aws-lambda, pnp-js

I have a scenario where I need to fetch lists data from Sharepoint sub sites.

My code is something like this.

```
const nodejs_1 = require("@pnp/nodejs");
const sp_1 = require("@pnp/sp"); 


let sitesArray = ['site1', 'site2', 'site3', 'site4', 'site5']
for(let i = 0; i < sitesArray.length; i++){
    let participants = await importParticipantsFromSharepoint(sitesArray[i]);
    console.log(participants)
}
//following is separate lambda function
function importParticipantsFromSharepoint(protocol_code){
        return new Promise( async function(resolve, reject) {  
            const participants = [];
            try{
                 sp_1.sp.setup({
                    sp: {
                        fetchClientFactory: function () {
                            //on each function call I am updating the base url
                            return new nodejs_1.SPFetchClient("https://abcd.sharepoint.com/Proj/Active/" + protocol_code, "********************", "**********************");
                        }
                    }
                });
                let w = await sp_1.sp.web.get();// at second iteration its still printing the data from first iteration
                console.log(JSON.stringify(w));// 
                sp_1.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Subject Tracking Log").items.top(1000).get().then(function (items) {
                    items.forEach(function(item){
                        
                    });
                    resolve(participants);
                });
            }catch(e){
                console.log(e)
                reject(e)
            }
        });
    }
```

My code is running in AWS Lambda.
Runtime: nodejs 10+

There are some participants added in the Sharepoint and I am trying to fetch them in order to save in db. Each site has unique participants like in site1 participants are p1, p2, p3 and in site2 participants are pp1, pp2, pp3. When my code runs for the site1 I get correct participants but for the site2 I get the wrong participants from site1. I have printed the logs and figured out that fetchClientFactory is not being updated. I dont have direct access to sharepoint and this is my first time with Sharepoint nodejs lib.

Comment: It's a singleton - see here: https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/blob/dc7cd8b929ee8ff28ed079c6fcf1ccd8084a7704/packages/sp/rest.ts#L78

Comment: Thanks, in this case how should I achieve the required results? any suggestion? I am trying get list of sub sites and then lists but could not figure the way.

Comment: I'm no SharePoint expert, but you should be able to avoid the singleton by constructing separate instances of SPRest yourself. If you make separate instances, and inject a new _runtime to each one (see constructor signature in the code linked above), you should be able to .setup() them independently.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I think I can use createIsolated.